# It´s possible to create a instance of a class using pointers?

Tags: c++

Let's say that I have a X pointer to some class Constructor, is there some way to call the `new` operator to create the instance?

I tried something like this :

```
#define Object 0xffffffff

Object test = new Object
```

But doesn't work. 
This pointer is just a example, I'm  trying to modify a game.

Comment: What does your pointer point to?

Comment: You can't have a pointer to a constructor

Comment: Google "placement new", it *may* be what you are reaching at.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to modify a binary program without having access to the source?

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I'm trying to add custom functionalities. I Injected some code hooking my DLL.

Comment: You will need to reverse engineer more than just function addresses in order to be able to pull something like that.

Comment: To call others member function from global instances I used the __thiscall convention, passing the instance address to ecx register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this doesn't work.

It's like calling `0xffffffff test = new 0xffffffff`. See? The statement doesn't make sense right

Comment: I have the pdb file here,  I was just wondering If I could create a instance of a class to use some methods.

Comment: What kind of data that your pdb has? Maybe I could figure out something better to fit your scenario

Comment: Everything. I'm using function pointer and the pointer 'this' to call some methods from global instances using a calling convention, but this class is only instantiated inside others functions and I'm only have it constructor point.

Comment: @Bruno do you mean nested classes? Like ``class A { class B { class C {};};};`` If so, you still have the full type info albeit access modifiers might be a problem. ``C *myC = new A::B::C()``.

Comment: I want something like that : In the executable there's a class Car with the member function Drive(). I only know the constructor pointer 0xffffffff  Car::Car. How do I create the car instance to call the method Drive?

Comment: @Bruno AFAIK C++ does not offer syntax to support pointers to constructors. Do you have the address of an already constructed object? You could do a `memcpy` on that to create another one (and cast it to the right type), provided that you know its size.